# Will you please delete me

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have discovered that this site is not what I had thought it to be, and am therefore asking you to remove as a poster. I had envisioned this as a site to comply with the great commission, and now that I have learned that it is not; I have no more reason to associate with the site. My preference as a Christian is to aid in enlarging the Kingdom and will devote my efforts to that end on another site.

Comment: This has been like four times since [the first about a year ago](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3577/is-it-possible-to-delete-cecil-beckum).

Answer (score 10):

As [Mr. Bultitude said](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4539/30) we do actually need you to trigger the delete yourself by following the steps in the help. Even as a moderator I can't actually just remove your account. When you do delete there will be a 24 safety timer to make sure you meant it, then it will go away. I believe you would need to do this separately for here and [your Biblical Hermeneutics account](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/3207/bye) if that is your intent.

Know that there will not be any hard feelings on this end. You have been a valuable contributor—but at the same time I do understand the conflict of purpose. I feel it too often enough, and most of my life's efforts are elsewhere: places where to great commission *can* be focused on. This site is only for a niche need and if your purposes don't happen to mesh with that niche then it may not be worth the investment.

I wish you the best wherever you go.

Comment: ditto. Well said, Caleb ;)

Answer (score 9):

If this is what you're set on doing, use the [contact form](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/contact) and select "I need to delete my user profile" from the drop-down.

But I would encourage you to either stick around, or at least keep your user profile up. Though this site is not here for the purpose of fulfilling the Great Commission, I think the fact that it exists to aid in the proliferation of knowledge/information *about* Christianity is a great aid to those seeking truth. There are many committed Christians here (including me), and I think that is in large part because we see the value of these questions and answers as an aid to our individual fulfillments of the Great Commission (and other aspects of daily Christian living).

But there's only so much we can do to convince you to stick around, and I understand if you want to head somewhere that has the Great Commission as its goal, where you can participate in that directly. It makes sense.

As for where you might go afterward, if you haven't yet figured that out, you might consider:

1. http://ChristianForums.com/
2. http://BaptistBoard.com/
3. http://ChristianAnswers.net/
4. http://Forums.CARM.org/

Whatever you decide, all the best to you.

Answer (score -6):

How about a cooling-off period?

Why don't you and I, along with all three moderators, @curiousdanii and @fredsbend grab a chat room and chat it up a bit? I'll make the chat room public so everyone can participate. Let's focus on what's wrong with this site and what we can do to make it better.

I don't want to lose your contribution and I know that a majority of Christianity.SE users feel the same way.

Comment: Cecil (User BYE) is mostly blind. He cannot effectively use the chat (at least that's what he told me). Further, I don't think anything is wrong with the site, though I'm flattered that you see me as important in this respect. (btw, [there's actually five mods](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)).

Answer (score -9):

I'm willing to change this site's charter if it means that you'll stay and won't self-delete yourself.

Please tell me how we've failed you, and I'll see what we can do.

Comment: This user has articulated their complaint many many times and its always basically the same. And he is right! But changing the site to be Great Commission friendly is just not in the cards and this answer is an empty promise at best.

Comment: @Caleb after having given myself a long period to reconsider my course of action, I have concluded that I am going to just you no longer use the site. It would be unfair to all of those people to whom I have given reps to take those away from them. I wish to thank you that you have acknowledged the validity of my objections. continued

Comment: @Caleb I do however believe that you may have misunderstood my meaning concerning the great commission. I did not and do not wish to see this site become evangelistic. However, I do believe that we should spread the gospel and by that, I mean that answering questions using a scriptural basis should be more than acceptable. As a personal note, the effort that it takes me to answer questions such are even to comment requires that I first put down my thoughts in Microsoft word then copy and paste and to the site. continued

Comment: @Caleb continued There are two processes in what I have to do, one is to dictate through a speech to text software, then have it read back to me through a text to speech software. This is necessary for error checking, but it is quite time consuming. It is frustrating to go to all of that work, and then have someone be little my efforts. While I realize, that many posters are not aware of the difficulty in my posting, however; I still find it abrasive. Perhaps I am too sensitive; but am unable to control my reaction. Therefore, I feel this is the best course of action. thanks for understanding.

Comment: @BYE Actually I'm pretty sure I **do** get where you are coming from re evangelism. I really do. But in spite of your seemingly perpetual optimism that this site would be conducive for that, I am convinced it's a bad match and will always be problematic. This sites' format and what it tries to accomplish is simply much more specialized. I'm not saying you are wrong to want what you want (I respect it quite a lot actually) I only think that you are mistaken to think that it would ever work here.

Comment: @BYE I appreciate all the work you do put it to opening the Scriptures to folks in spite of the extra work it requires and I hope you find a venue in which that investment can be used effectively. I'm sure there are sites with more forum-like discussion formats where your knowledge of and heart for the Word would be well placed.

Comment: @bye I must comment, as a grammar and format obsessivist, I am quite content with your answers in that respect. And considering your disability, you forward much more to being clear and neat than probably most people even notice. I have appreciated your efforts to this site, thus far, and if you do continue, focusing on questions that ask for the "biblical basis" is probably the best type for your knowledge set.